# Is it possible to use an NHibernate type discriminator as part of a foreign key

Tags: nhibernate

Taking the following object model:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Category : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<LocalizedProperty> LocalizedProperties { get; set; }
}

public class Product : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<LocalizedProperty> LocalizedProperties { get; set; }
}

public class LocalizedProperty : Entity
{
    public string CultureName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to use a type discriminator along with the entity's Id as the foreign key. The idea is that the resultant LocalizedProperties table would be:

```
LocalizedProperties
-------------------
Id
EntityType
EntityId
CultureName
PropertyName
PropertyValue
```

I know this is possible using Table-per-subclass mapping where each of my "Localized" entities inherit from a base localized entity class, which in turn has the association with LocalizedProperty. However, I would rather not have this extra level of inheritance if the above is possible.

Thanks,
Ben

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Diego for providing the solution using confORM. For those of you using traditional mapping files, I have converted the example from http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/11/conform-any-to-many.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace="ConfOrm.UsageExamples.CreateXmlMappingsInBinFolder" assembly="ConfOrm.UsageExamples" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Blog">
    <id name="Id" type="Guid">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Title" />
    <property name="Subtitle" />
    <set name="Tags" cascade="all" where="TagedItemClass = 'ConfOrm.UsageExamples.CreateXmlMappingsInBinFolder.Blog'">
      <key column="TagedItemId" foreign-key="none" />
      <one-to-many class="Tag" />
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace="ConfOrm.UsageExamples.CreateXmlMappingsInBinFolder" assembly="ConfOrm.UsageExamples" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Tag">
    <id name="Id" type="Guid">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <any id-type="Guid" name="TagedItem">
      <column name="TagedItemClass" />
      <column name="TagedItemId" />
    </any>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<any>`.

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-anymapping

For a full example, check http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/11/conform-any-to-many.html. I think it's exactly what you need.

Comment: can you explain how I would use this mapping in my example as I'm struggling to see it, based on the nhforge example?

Comment: this looks perfect. Do you know if this can be achieved with traditional mapping or is it specific to confORM?

Comment: @Ben you can use xml mapping without a problem. Maybe Fluent too (haven't tried)

Comment: thank you very much. I was able to generate the mapping files using confORM.